Access VITE env variables from Azure Static Web App
I'm deploying a React/Vite app on Azure web app (the staging part) and find myself not being able to access my .env variable.
I deployed a Node/Express server the same way and when I input my environment variables in Azure settings, they are recognized and affected.
For Vite, it is different since they are build time variables and not runtime variables. So I tried to set them up in my build pipeline, the yml created by Azure, and used GitHub variables to keep them protected.
This is how my URL variable is defined in my frontend in my config-global.js:
export const HOST_API = import.meta.env.VITE_HOST_API;

Now in my .env file, I define:
VITE_HOST_API=https://staging.api.my-website.com

And here is my YAML file where the build pipeline is made:
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - my-website-staging-front

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip -r release.zip dist

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'my-website-staging-front'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.SECRET_STUFF }}
          package: dist
        env:
          VITE_HOST_API: $BASE_URL_STAGING

The last line is what I added in my GitHub variable which is BASE_URL_STAGING=https://staging.api.my-website.com.
And finally in my Azure environment variables I set:
VITE_HOST_API=https://staging.api.my-website.com

So far all my requests are using the URL https://staging.my-website.com for every request which means that the HOST_API that defined the base URL to use for every query is undefined and therefore the query use the base URL of the website they are on, in this case https://staging.my-website.com.
I tried using process-envify but it did not work.

So the problem was when, where and how I was created my environment variable in the build. This is the new version of my YAML file:

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - my-website-staging-front

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      - name: Set environment variables
        run: echo "VITE_HOST_API=${{ secrets.BASE_URL_STAGING }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV 
        // Append the environment variable to the special GitHub environment file

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        env:
          VITE_HOST_API: ${{ secrets.BASE_URL_STAGING }} //
        // Set the environment variable for this step

        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip -r release.zip dist

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'my-website-staging-front'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.SECRET_STUFF }}
          package: dist



